# java script button not showing

Tags: javascript, html

ok i have this code (which i got from paul irish page+ some modifications) (it gives you your ie version (standar stuff):

```
 <!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
 <!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>test:</h1>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function test()) {
"use strict";
// Detecting IE
var oldIE
if ($('html').is('.ie6, .ie7, .ie8')) {
    oldIE = true;
}
if (oldIE) == true {
document.write("version<ie9")

} else {
   document.write(" version => ie9")

}
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
<button type="button" onclick="test()">testing</button>
</script>
</body>

 </html>
```

the thing is it isnt showing the testing button

Comment: I could be wrong but I'm pretty sure you don't need your button to be in between script tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<button>` element should not be surrounded by `<script>` tags. After all, it's HTML, not JavaScript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>A HTML document needs a title to be valid.</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="test">I feel so clickable today.</button>

<!-- You must include jQuery before you can use its methods -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
"use strict";

    (function ($) {
        // Assignment with the ternary operator
        var oldIE = ($('html').is('.ie6, .ie7, .ie8')) ? true : false;

        // You need at least jQuery 1.7 to use .on()
        $('#test').on('click', function() {
            console.log(oldIE);
        });
    }(jQuery));

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

*N.B.* I included jQuery because I saw a `$` symbol in your code.

---

Since you *should* be using the console during development, here's a snippet that safeguards against JS errors in browsers that don't provide a console.

```
// Avoid `console` errors in browsers that lack a console
(function(){var e;var t=function(){};var n=["assert","clear","count","debug","dir","dirxml","error","exception","group","groupCollapsed","groupEnd","info","log","markTimeline","profile","profileEnd","table","time","timeEnd","timeStamp","trace","warn"];var r=n.length;var i=window.console=window.console||{};while(r--){e=n[r];if(!i[e]){i[e]=t}}})();
```

Comment: Great. I added some other things in there too, which may help you along your way :)

Comment: yeah ty, but i dont get why im not getting a result

Comment: The value of `oldIE` is being printed to the console. [You can test the code here](http://jsfiddle.net/GcS4n/).

Comment: there we go, im getting this error : ie2.html, line 16 character 6 jQuery is undefined, okay i got why the error is, but i will have to do it from the other code, since for what we need it when we run it we cant access the console, still ty so much

Comment: It will say `jQuery is undefined` when you haven't included jQuery. The jQuery library should be included before any of its methods are used in your script. Also, it's a good habit to use the JavaScript console liberally during development. Paul Irish created a small script that will safeguard against JS errors in browsers that don't provide a console. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

But if you wanted to keep it in the script tag you would need to modify your code like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   document.write('<button type="button" onclick="test()">testing</button>');
</script>
```